# How to configure the Provisioning Profile for a .net6 iOS application in Azure DevOps?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, xamarin.ios, .net-6.0

I have migrated my iOS application from `Xamarin.iOS` to `.net6` using the `iOS workload`.

Everything builds and runs locally on the iOS simulator.

The application's code resides in Azure DevOps and built there:

[image: CI/CD]

The `dotnet build` task throws the following error:

```
Xamarin.Shared.targets(1550,3): Error : Could not find any available provisioning profiles for Application.iOS on iOS
```

The `Xamarin.iOS` task had a place to specify the provisioning profile:

[image: Xamarin.iOS Task]

**Question**

How can I specify the iOS provisioning profile in the `dotnet build` task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that there are two tasks that replaces part of what the Xamarin.iOS task was doing.

The 1st one is the [Install Apple Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate?view=azure-devops) task.

I have uploaded my signing certificate and configured a variable to hold my password:

[image: Install Apple Certificate]

The 2nd one is the [Install Apple provisioning profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops) and *this* is the answer to the question. I just had to download the Provisioning profile I retrieved from the Apple Developer account and uploaded it in the Task.

[image: Install Apple provisioning profile]